# What strategies are there for writing a load testing tool?

Tags: c#, multithreading, load-testing

I know about tools for load testing a WCF service, so please don't suggest I use one.

If I wanted to write a tool for calling a service (or invoking any action really) X times a second for Y seconds, what things do I need to consider?

My initial approach would be to have a timer fire at the required interval and create a task when it fires, but I'm concerned that this will simply queue a lot of tasks up waiting for threads from the thread pool to execute on and they will not invoke the service at the required times.

Would creating individual threads to do the work be better?  Then I'd be concerned about creating a large number of threads.

So what strategies can I use?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your goals for scalability. Running a single session per thread is easier - the code is much simpler to run a series of synchronous I/O transactions on a thread. You can spawn thousands of threads on Windows and Linux, if tuned properly.  If you need to scale much farther than that, then you'll need to use asynchronous I/O APIs and setup a pools of threads to service groups of those I/O channels.  I'd suggest making the thread-to-I/O-channel ratio configurable and monitor the idle time of the threads in those pools...perhaps even allowing the pools to add more threads when needed.